# Nodejs redirect not working inside a Docker container

Tags: express, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers :

1- Api

2- Authorization

From Authorization, I'd like to redirect the users requests to my `API` if they pass the authentication.

So inside my authentication container, I have :

```
if ( itsAuthenticated){
     req.redirect('http://api:8080/users/something')
    // req is the normall express request object
}
```

`http://api:8080` refers to my other container which exposes `8080` and I have linked it inside my `docker-compose` file as below :

```
  api:
    build: ./api
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    links:
    - mongo // api needs mongo and it's working fine
    volumes:
    - ./api:/code

  authorization:
    build: ./authorization
    ports:
    - "8088:8088"
    volumes:
    - ./authorization:/code
    links:
    - api // here I have a link to api container
   ...
```

**NOTE:**

If I make an HTTP request from `authorization` to my `API`, it works.

Bellow works fine :

```
if ( itsAuthenticated){
    const result = await http.get('http://api:8080/users/something');
    console.log('**** result',result);
}
```

So basically, the connections are fine, the `get` request is fine, the redirect is fully working outside `Docker`, but when inside the container, the `redirect` doesn't work.

Appreciate the help.

**UPDATE**

Just realised that if I redirect my requests to `http://www.google.com`, I get a result, but it dies immediately when I redirect it to `http://api:8080/users/something`

I'm sure I'm missing something silly somewhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send that redirect call, these three steps happen:

1. The browser contacts, say, `http://localhost:8088/` and sends a login request.
2. The authorization server says "oh, 302, you should contact `http://api:8080`."
3. The browser tries to contact `http://api:8080`.

Since the redirect will really take effect in the browser, you have to send back a URL the browser will understand, which means it can't use the Docker-internal DNS name.

The easy, development-oriented answer is to use `http://localhost:8080` as the redirect address.  Since you're using Express, a recipe like

```
req.redirect(`http://${req.hostname}:8080/users/something`)
```

might work (using [Request.hostname](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname)), though this forces your application to know about the other service's published port.

Comment: Thank you so much, this absolutely makes sense and it works. But I don't want to expose my `8080` port to the browser, I want to only expose my authorization to the browser , which is `8088` . How do I do that ?

Comment: I guess redirect is a bad idea, I should do some kind of proxying ? Basically, I want my auth layer to protect all the requests and only let them through if authenticated.